# Java combine multiple collections efficiently

Tags: java, collections, merge

I have the following lines, part of a larger function:

```
Collection<String> idSet; //idset != successors.keys()
Map<String, ArrayList> successors; // parameter to larger function
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String id: idSet) {
        ArrayList<String> idsuccessors = this.successors.get(id);
        result.addAll(idSuccessors);
      }
```

I want to combine all values from the mapping successors into a single collection. Although the above code works, I assume there must be a cleaner way (e.g. in Python I achieved it in a single, short line).

```
result = set.union(*[set(successors(id)) for id in ids])
```

Note that it is not a problem to convert the type of the Mapping from ArrayList to for example a HashSet, should that help.

Any advise is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make it much shorter, unless you use a library (such as guava) which will probably have some static method that does that.

Comment: use a guava MultiMap instead of implementing your own. It comes with a values() method. If you need the ids as well, use entries(). If you can't, your solution is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2-liner using the new Java 8 streams:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
successors.values().forEach(result::addAll);
```

I'm sure there is a one-liner lurking about somewhere, but I haven't found it